# How do I get the search bar to show up in this Geocoder Google maps api example?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, input

I am referring to this example: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple

For some reason my input box appears as a small white square in the top left hand corner of the box, and I can't type anything into it...I've followed the example almost exactly, but for some reason am not getting the same result..

The HTML in my version is

```
<div class="map myboardmap">
  <div id="panel">
     <input id="address" type="textbox" value="Sydney, NSW"></input>
     <input type="button" value="Geocode" onclick="codeAddress()"></input>
  </div>
<div id="myboardmap_canvas"></div>
```

and the CSS is

```
#panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -180px;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

#myboardmap_canvas{
width:400px;
height:300px;
background:#000;
border-radius:20px;
-moz-border-radius:20px;
-webkit-border-radius:20px;

-moz-box-shadow:5px 5px 7px rgba(33,33,33,1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 7px rgba(33,33,33,.7);
     box-shadow: 5px 5px 7px rgba(33,33,33,.7);
}

.map{
z-index:1;
display:block;
position: absolute;

-moz-transition:-moz-transform .15s linear;
-o-transition:-o-transform .15s linear;
-webkit-transition:-webkit-transform .15s linear;

border-radius:20px;
-moz-border-radius:20px;
-webkit-border-radius:20px;
}

.myboardmap{
z-index:1;
top:30px;
left:500px;

  -o-transform:rotate(3deg);
  -webkit-transform:rotate(3deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(3deg);
}
```

The JS is:

```
var geocoder;
var myboardmap;

function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.5072, -0.1275);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: latlng
    }
    myboardmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('myboardmap_canvas'), mapOptions);

    ...
}

function codeAddress() {
    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': address
    }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: myboardmap,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
        } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }
    });
}

...

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I've had a look at 'inspect element' and there is an error: Cannot call method 'addDomListener' of undefined (anonymous function)

Comment: Please show the exact code you used. You can [edit] your question and put it in.

Comment: It's good to show complete file (JavaScript and HTML) because problem could be HTML part.

Comment: The posted code doesn't exhibit the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/MV84n/

Comment: thanks for pointing that out..It doesn't work in my full code, so perhaps there is something else I've missed in the css or the rest of the JS which is having a strange effect. I'll have another look at my code..

Answer (score 0):

found it! the problem was this tiny bit of css:

```
input {display:none}
```